# how to install DB.php?

Tags: php, database

I have use DB::Connect in my program for accessing the database.
I ran my php program this shows the error

DB.php file is not their.

> require_once 'DB.php';
>
> PEAR::setErrorHandling(PEAR_ERROR_DIE);

Then I copy the DB.php file and  PEAR.php file from another machine to my
machine after that If I ran from command line it didn't through the error.
while running from browser this shows error. How to solve this problem.?
How to install this DB.php?

Comment: Where is this DB.php from? Is it delivered from PEAR? OR did you download it somewhere?

Comment: I have used my program in my machine . its working file. when I run my program to another machine it shows the error. DB.php file is not their. then I copied the DB.php file from my machine. and I placed this file in "/usr/share/php" after that if I run from command line it didn't show the error. but while running from browser its not working.

Comment: "not working" says little about your problem. If it worked, you'd not be posting here.

Answer (score 4):

PEAR provides a command line installer that should take care of all the details:

```
pear install DB
```

Since PEAR packages are mainly PHP code, you can also copy the files manually, but you must make sure you copy everything, not only the first required file, and your script must also be able to find the files so you must add pear to the `include_path` PHP directive.

Comment: Actually ... when I am running the file in CLI it working fine. When I am running the same file in web browser , the conection function get blocked .... And more thing is that I have used pg_connect function it is working fine in both side (CLI and Web browser ) . Now my doubt is why DB::connect get blocking in web browser...?

Comment: I don't know what is the problem?  thats why I posted here. If you don't know the answer your don't answer for this.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry for not fulfilling your high customer support quality standards and wasting your invaluable time with answers that do not work. I'll be glad to offer a refund.